# Using bash scripting to search for file on another server using wild cards

Tags: shell-script, find, wildcards

What am I doing wrong here. I am not very experienced in bash but trying. In summary, I am trying to ssh from one box(management), and find in a file named "Debug-EmapiTagwireConnector-Wire-2022-05-24"*" exists in that directory. This file is located inside procIP=10.1.2.3 . The script manages to ssh to that location but I cannot seem to be able to grep or locate the script. I know that this file exists here ~/TTT/system/taxm1/Debug-EmapiTagwireConnector-Wire-2022-05-24--15.51.43.log but I cannot seem to grep it. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

dateToday=$(date -d today +%Y'-'%m'-'%d)

function validateLog()
{
tax=~/HealthChecks/cfg/taxm.cfg
if [ -e "$tax" ];
then
        for i in `cat $tax`
        do
                myIP=`$getServerDetail $i`
                DebugLog=$(find ./ -type f -name "Debug-EmapiTagwireConnector-Wire-2022-05-24*")
                ssh ${USER}@$myIP "cd ~/TTT/system/$i; if [ -f ${DebugLog} ]; then echo "${DebugLog} found." ; else echo "Failed to locate file."; exit 1; fi" ||
                                                {

                                                        $logWriter "Connection to ${i} failed. Exiting script." 1
                                                        exit 1
                                                 }
                $logWriter "Validation completed." 0
        done
        exit 0
else
        $logWriter "CFG is missing." 1
        exit 1
fi
}

validateLog
```

Comment: Seems like your logic is wrong - your first `ssh` command will return `0` if the folder does *not* exist. Also, you have quoting issues in the second `ssh` command (use https://shellcheck.net)

Comment: Why are you using `find /path/ -type f | grep filename` rather than `find /path/ -type f -name filename`?

Comment: Thank you both. I amended the code as above.

first problem is that DebugLog=$(find ./ -type f -name "Debug-EmapiTagwireConnector-Wire-2022-05-24*")

Second problem is that the code does not exist properly.

Comment: I managed to resolve this. Now I can find the files. I however need to output the file names and size of the file somewhere.

Comment: Make `find` and `stat` do all the dirty work:  `find /path/ -type f -name filename -exec stat -c '%s %n' {} \;`